# superset dashboard with a where clause coming from field

Tags: apache-superset

I have a SQL table with 2 columns: CreatedDate and keyword.

Every day, new entries are inserted in this table.

I want to build a Superset dashboard that displays the new keywords (not the new lines) since a given date.

In SQL, I would do this:

```html
DECLARE @sourcedate DATE;
SET @sourcedate = '2024-01-25';
DECLARE @oldestdate DATE;
SET @oldestdate = '2024-01-01';
SELECT a.*
FROM SearchAnalytics a
LEFT JOIN SearchAnalytics b ON a.Keyword = b.Keyword AND b.CreatedDate = CAST(@oldestdate AS DATE)
WHERE a.CreatedDate = CAST(@sourcedate AS DATE) AND b.Keyword IS NULL
```

This quey returns the new keywords since January 1.  This is exactly what I want to display in the Superset dashboard.

Ideally SourceDate should be filled automatically (today's date or Max(CreatedDate) from table).
And oldestdate is the date we want to compare to.
I imagine a dashboard where we enter the oldest date and it returns the list of new keywords since this date.

ex: If the table contains these entries, the dashboard should display stackoverflow2

01/01/2024 stackoverflow

02/01/2024 stackoverflow

03/01/2024 stackoverflow

03/01/2024 stackoverflow2

Nothing in the GUI allows me to enter this query:

[image]